# Check if local storage successfully changed

Tags: angularjs, local-storage

I'm using `LocalStorageModule`.

```
myApp.factory('myService', function($rootScope, localStorageService) {
    return {
      addSomething : function(name) {
        ...
        var ret = localStorageService.set('something', lotsOfData);
        alert(ret);
        return ret;
      }
    }
 }
```

In this case, `ret` is `true`, even if the data hasn't been successfully added or hasn't changed. Is there a way to check if the addition was effective?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply read the data stored in the local storage, and compare it to expected value:

```
localStorageService.set('foo', foo);
if (!angular.equals(localStorageService.get('foo'), foo)) {
    throw "The data hasn't been successfully added to the local storage.";
}
```

Comment: Yes... this is the workaround, but I'm hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: @JakabfiAttila There's none. What's dirty in this one?